# How to exchange authorization code with token in Auth0 when authorization server behind a proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, auth0, netflix-zuul

I am working on a spring boot web application where the application is hosted behind a Zuul reverse proxy server and API gateway is nginx. All the applications are running on the same virtual machine (NginX, Zuul, and My App)
Nginx does the SSL termination and zull is responsible for request authentication and authorization. I am using OpenID Connect for user authentication with Auth0.

Flow of a request

```
Browser --(A)--> NginX --(B)--> Zuul --(c)--> My Application
```

A - https call with domain name eg: https://example.com

B - http call for locally running Zull server eg: http://127.0.0.1:7070

In nginx server I have given a rule to forward all the traffic to locally running Zull server

https://example.com --> http://127.0.0.1:7070

With this configuration, callback URL is set as https://example.com/callback at Auth0 and once the callback url is called then it will be sent to the zuul server with a different name.

```
https://example.com/callback?code=sf4sf4ds4fdf --> http://127.0.0.1:7070/callback?code=sf4sf4ds4fdf
```

I have used libraries provided by Auth0 to exchange the authorization code for token. but at this point the request for the token contains the callback url as http://127.0.0.1:7070/callback and not as https://example.com/callback (This is what i registered at Auth0 and used to get the authorization code). Therefore the system always throws and error.

I can get this to work by removing nginx server and directly keeping the zuul server in front (Then there is no url changes). is there any way to make this work with my existing configuration.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems, at the moment this issue can not be resolved because the request for exchanging the token for authorized code is built inside a library provided by Auth0 **(mvc-auth-common-1.0.2.jar)**. Callback url is generated by calling **req.getRequestURL().toString()**.

Since the request was sent by the nginx proxy to the zull server, request url is always https://127.0.0.1:7070

In order to be successful, I had to use a little hack. I wrapped the request object using a custom http request wrapper.

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
class CustomRequesWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

        public CustomRequesWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
            super(request);
        }

        @Override
        public StringBuffer getRequestURL() {
            return new StringBuffer("https://example.com/callback");
        }
    }
```

Here I am returning the required url.

```
// Tokens tokens = controller.handle(req); -- previous code 
Toke tokens = controller.handle(new CustomRequesWrapper(req)); // current code
```

Now whenever the method **getRequestURL()** method is called, my domain name will be passed.